how to apply function on nested dictionary values
I have a nested dict with different levels of nesting
dict1 = {
    'A': {'a': 1},
    'B': 2,
    'C': {'c': 3},
    'D': {'d': {'dd': 4}}
}

I want to perform (for instance) key-wise multiplication. With flat dict this is straightforward:
{k: v * 2 for k, v in dict.items()}

How can I do the same in the above dict?

One approach will be to find a 1:1 mapping between nested dict and the corresponding flattened dict with tuples as keys dict2  = {('A', 'a}: 1, ('D', 'd', 'dd): 4

The most natural method is a recursive function that walks over the input map and returns the new one.

Please only ask one question per post. Your title seems to describe the follow-up question, not the main question.

@Barmar, I've moved the follow-up question into a different SO thread

You should update this title, since it no longer has anything to do with two dictionaries.

You can write a recursive function which applies a function to all non-dict values it finds:
def perform_func_on_values(d, func):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            perform_func_on_values(v, func)
        else:
            d[k] = func(v)

dict1 = {
'A': {'a': 1},
'B': 2,
'C': {'c': 3},
'D': {'d': {'dd': 4}}
}

print(dict1)
perform_func_on_values(dict1, lambda val:val*2)
print(dict1)

Output:
{'A': {'a': 1}, 'B': 2, 'C': {'c': 3}, 'D': {'d': {'dd': 4}}}
{'A': {'a': 2}, 'B': 4, 'C': {'c': 6}, 'D': {'d': {'dd': 8}}}

See how this is an in-place change.
